# enthalpy of formation of hydronium

Tags: enthalpy

Can someone explain how the enthalpy of formation of aqueous hydronium was determined. It appears to be exactly the same as the enthalpy of formation of liquid water. I know this must have something to do with the fact that the aqueous hydrogen cation has an enthalpy of formation of 0 by definition, but I can't see how.

I'm looking in the appendices of two different general chem texts, the ones by Atkins, Jones, and Laverman; and the one by Oxtoby et al. In both cases, liquid water and aqueous hydronium are both shown as having enthalpies of formation of -285.83 kJ/mol.

I think I understand the answer to my question based on Maurice's reply.

Here's an example.

Consider the following two reactions:

$\ce{Cl^-(aq) +H_3O^+(aq) -> HCl(aq) +H_2O(l)}$

$\ce{Cl^-(aq) +H^+(aq)-> HCl(aq)}$

(Thank for you for the formatting tips @orthocresol. Very helpful.)

Since aqueous hydronium and aqueous hydrogen ions are the same, we expect these two reactions to have the same reaction enthalpy.  And since aqueous hydrogen ions have an enthalpy of formation of 0 (by definition), the only way the two reactions will have the same reaction enthalpy is if hydronium and water have the same enthalpies of formation.

Comment: The aqueous hydrogen cation and the aqueous hydroniun are synonym. They are not different from one another. $\ce{H3O^+}$ may be called aqueous hydronium or aqueous hydrogen cation.

Comment: Because nobody is sure that aqueous hydrogen cation is always made of $\ce{H3O^+}$. Some scientists think that Hydrogen cations may also be making more complex ions in water, like $\ce{H5O2^+}$ or even$\ce{H_{2n+1}O_n^+}$ with n>2.

Comment: Well, let's say you have the reaction $$\ce{H+ + H2O -> H3O+}.$$ Then we have that $$\Delta_\mathrm{r} H = \Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H3O+}) - \Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H2O}) - \Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H+}).$$ It follows that if—and only if—the reaction enthalpy $\Delta_\mathrm{r}H$ is zero, then $\Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H3O+}) = \Delta_\mathrm{f} H(\ce{H2O})$. But I don't immediately see why that should be zero (I welcome any pointers!).

Comment: It would be useful if you could share the source that you are quoting, i.e. what book (or website or whatever) gives you a value for $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H (\ce{H3O+})$. My usual reference (the appendix of Atkins *Physical Chemistry* 9th ed) doesn't provide this value.

Comment: On the solvation models, Wikipedia has a good set of references discussing a few works that seek to ID what those structures look like - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium#Solvation

Comment: @orthocresol - bottom line is that the reaction enthalpy for the reaction you wrote out is 0 because the aqueous hydrogen ion and the aqueous hydronium ion are the same thing and so the reaction is essentially a "null reaction".

Comment: I thought of that, and I can see why, but I just have a bad feeling that that opens a separate can of worms. It should be possible, at least, to construct a series of formation enthalpies that are internally consistent using this logic (such as that shown in your question). So my concern might be unfounded. BTW, you can use `$\ce{...}$` to typeset chemical formulae/equations correctly (and more easily): `$\ce{H+ + H2O -> H3O+}$` $\ce{H+ + H2O -> H3O+}$ is correct, `$H^+ + H_2O \to H_3O^+$` $H^+ + H_2O \to H_3O^+$ is italicised (not right).